# Warning: Illegal string offset - on homepage

Tags: plugin-development, errors

I have a question regarding an issue that has just recently been causing issues with my website. I have been getting a fatal string error from my website just wondering if anyone knows how to resolve this issue or has had a similar problem and found a solution to it.
[image: Illegal String offset]

Answer (score 0):

It' an error in the 'flatsome' theme. You need to contact the theme developer via their support page.

Unless you want to dig around in their code, fix something, then have a theme update break things again. (Not recommended, but if you are headed that way, make a child theme).

The theme support page is your best next stop.